# Browser not specified error when using testcaferc.js file

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using the testcaferc.js file for congfiguration.

And I see the following error when I run the test:

*An error has occurred while reading the ".....testcaferc.js" configuration file.
ERROR Cannot find the browser. "./test1.js" is neither a known browser alias, nor a path to an executable file.*

[image]

**My project has the following folders/files:**

1. node modules folder
2. .testcaferc.js
3. package-lock.json
4. package.json
5. test1.js

**1. The contents of .testcaferc.js**

[image]

Note: I have tried all sorts of quotes to specify the browser, but none of the combination worked. some examples below:

```
module.exports = {
    skipJsErrors: true,
    "browsers": "chrome"
    // other settings
}
```

or

```
module.exports = {
   skipJsErrors: true,
   browsers: "chrome"
}
```

or

```
module.exports = {
 skipJsErrors: true,
 browsers: 'chrome'
}
```

**2. The contents of test1.js file**
[image]

**3. The contents of package.json**
[image]

**4. And lastly, the contents of the error log file:**
[image]

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error you mentioned, but I did not succeed. It looks like we need more information. Is the shared content of `.testcaferc.js` the entire content? How do you run tests: from the console or with `TestRun`?
Please share all the information we need to reproduce the bug. If possible, please create a reproducible example as shown here: https://testcafe.io/402636/faq?search#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue.

Comment: Hi @IlyaAfanasenko, i have now edited my question to give more information. hope this could help.

Comment: The configuration file name must start with a dot. Please check this.

Comment: @msilori did you have a chance to see my updated answer?

Comment: hey @IlyaAfanasenko, you were correct in saying that i was missing the dot before the name of the testcaferc.json file.   Testcafe now seems to work with json type of config file. But, the problem in using the .testcaferc.js still persists. thanks.

Comment: Adding the dot before my .testcaferc.js made it work, thank you @IlyaAfanasenko . Saved me hours of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally, after a lot of confusions and revision of my code, I could get my test running with ***.testcaferc.js***

I got to know that the **type:"module"** should not be there in the package.json to work with my test.js file

Also noticed that if we write any incorrect code in the **.testcaferc.js** file, it will keep showing the error similar to the following in the terminal:

An error has occurred while reading the "....testcaferc.js" configuration file.
ERROR Cannot find the browser. "./test1.js" is neither a known browser alias, nor a path to an executable file.

Hope it would help someone, who stumbles across this issue. thnx.

Comment: Removing `type` from `package.json` resulted in `npm test` not having an error, despite omitting the required `browsers` arg in your `testcafe` command?

Comment: An alternative may be to keep type as is, and change the export in testcaferc to be `export default {...}` (assuming testcafe supports it).

Answer (score 0):

The npm `test` script is missing the target browser. Docs recommend using `all` as an alias to use locally installed browsers, which is what `browsers` defines in the rc file.

```
"test": "testcafe all ./test1.js"
```

See [Getting Started](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402635/getting-started) for more info.

---

[Example .testcaferc.js](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#javascript) (Docs):

```
let os = require("os");

module.exports = {
    skipJsErrors: true,
    hostname: os.hostname(),
    // other settings
}
```

Note that `browsers` can be a single browser String or an Array of multiple browsers, so that isn't the issue ([Docs](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#browsers)).

Comment: I guess it should work without it being specified as an array as it is only a single browser.

I tried with and without the array, and same results :(

Comment: Hey @JBallin thanks for the response. I dont want to use the npm script to specify the browsers. I wish to use the config file to let testcafe decide which browser to use.

Comment: @msilori correct, that's what my answer does. "all" will use the config file. Did you try it? It's a required argument to the CLI, you can't omit it.

Comment: Hey @JBallin, as per the documentation, the "all" is an alias, which could be used when someone wants to run tests in all of the locally installed browsers. It is not a mandatory thing and can very well be omitted. For example, if someone wants to run the tests in just one of the browsers, using "all" would be incorrect.

Comment: @msilori Agree that it doesn't make much sense, but I'm hoping it will either work or the output will guide as. Have you tried it? Where do you see that browsers arg in CLI isn't mandatory? [These docs](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402830/guides/basic-guides/run-tests#command-line-interface) say it is.

Comment: @msilori Possibly the arguments are optional, but only if you omit them both or only omit browsers - you can't expect to be able to pass only `src` (same way you can't only define `b` in `(a = 1, b = 3) => a + b`). How about you try either defining `src` in your config file and then simply running `npx testcafe` or try setting browsers to `[]`, which hopefully will look at config file (`npx testcafe [] ./test1.js`).

Comment: You can also try empty string `''` instead of `[]` for browsers.

Comment: 1. Where do you see that browsers arg in CLI isn't mandatory?

Answer: Where did I mention that the browser args isnt mandatory. The only thing that I was trying to explain is that the "all" keyword isnt mandatory. We could use "Chrome" instead of "all" to launch the test in just one of the locally installed browsers. 

If you have only "Chrome" specified in your config file, and if you try to use the "all" keyword in the CLI, it will overwrite the browser options from the config file. The "all" in the CLI will instead launch the tests in all the locally installed browsers.

Comment: My original post was anyways related to using the config file and the browser option specified there, so i guess our discussion is bit out of scope by mentioning too much about the CLI args.  :)

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. But I still think the missing CLI arg is the issue. Did you try my suggestions?

Comment: @msilori did you try it?

Comment: yes, i tried the "all" but it did not work. The only thing that solved this is removing the   type:"module" from my package.json file.

Comment: @msilori aren't you still getting the error when calling the CLI (that's what your answer suggests)? Have you tried either setting the `src` in `.testcaferc.js` instead of passing in the CLI, or passing either `""`/`[]` in the CLI (instead of `all`)? I mentioned both of these in my most recent comments - I planned to update my answer once you confirmed which one worked/you prefer.

Comment: Note that when I say "CLI" I'm referring to the `testcafe` command in your `npm test` script.

Comment: hey @JBallin i am not getting any errors when I remove the key value (```type:"module"```) from package.json.

I tried your suggestion as well like putting empty browser list in the config, setting the src to the testfile url, and using the testcafe command in the npm script. It does not work. The only solution was removing the ```type:"module"``` key/value from package.json : )

Comment: Interesting I didn't find the logic for testcafe to handle omitting the browsers arg and I don't see why setting src wouldn't work. Appreciate the feedback, I'll update my answer soon.